# How to design same timeline like instagram has using a single UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to design a app which is same as instagram timeline which contains user post , post like someone has send a photo, or some one has sent a video, so i want to display the all post together in a single tableview.

so i'm doing the same with UITableView and playing videos with AVPlayer on image view layer and displaying images in image view.

But i can not able to manage the videos buffering. and the multiple images and videos. is there any easy solution?

Is there any library which helps to display video and image together in a UITableView cell?

Comment: Instagram have open sourced their timeline code: https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AsyncDisplayKit](http://asyncdisplaykit.org) to replace UIKit to do what you want to implement. It have `ASVideoNode` can support play video on `ASTableNode`

It have lots of [examples](https://github.com/facebook/AsyncDisplayKit/tree/master/examples), you can try it.